# BitmapImage and DownloadProgressEventHandler values are not smooth

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I've followed the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage) about how to use the `DownloadProgressEventHandler` for `BitmapImage`

My code is slightly different to the example as it's in C++ but it looks like this...

```
BitmapImage^ im = ref new BitmapImage();
im->DownloadProgress += ref new DownloadProgressEventHandler(this, &Capture::ShowDownloadProgress);
im->ImageOpened += ref new RoutedEventHandler(this, &Capture::ImageDownloaded);

void ColonyCounter::Capture::ShowDownloadProgress(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::DownloadProgressEventArgs^ e) {
    imgLoadProgress->Value = e->Progress;
}
```

This appears to work however it's not smooth. The progress value jumps around. I've provided a link to a video [here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMEfKueywQclgvOouwoe2WRl48-8GkPv4cEtBGduT0UuUSEmUCaTbL-rOEbsdTqnw?key=N09lYlZPaEgyY0dQQk91c3hOaGF6ZTB2a0NqREpB) that best demonstrates this problem.

It appears to be showing the progress of multiple chunks.

I'm also using this

```
im->ImageOpened += ref new RoutedEventHandler(this, &Capture::ImageDownloaded);
```

to determine when it has completed, this correctly only fires once when the image download is complete.

**Edit**
I'm using platform 10.0.14393.0, VS2015

I'm currently just using random wallpaper images to test at the moment. My source image is from http://www.wallpaperup.com/wallpaper/download/21969
However, when I test it with https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/hs-2015-02-a-hires_jpg.jpg
it doesn't appear to occur and I get a nice smooth download progress bar.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with your code snippet. Could you please provide your testing environment and a [mcve] ? I'm testing on windows 10 OS build 15063 on local machine.

Comment: I'll try get round to producing a mcve. In the meantime I've added some further info about image sources and when the behaviour is observed or not.